# Comma separated floats in C++

Tags: c++, io

I am trying to separate a list of numbers such as: 34,45,12.3,100,34.6,50

I can do it only if there are no decimals like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "34,45,12.3,100,34.6,50";
    std::vector<int> vect;

    std::stringstream ss(str);

    int i;

    while (ss >> i)
    {
        vect.push_back(i);

        if (ss.peek() == ',')
            ss.ignore();
    }

    for (i=0; i< vect.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vect.at(i)<<std::endl;

}
```

The problem here is with the decimals. The above will produce:

```
34 45 12 3 100 34 6 50
```

while it should produce:

```
34 45 12.3 100 34.6 50
```

basically the above code when it sees a dot `'.'` it acts as if it was a comma.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a vector of `int` as in integer, thus it cannot hold a floating point number; they get truncated to the integer part. Change your vector so that its elements are floating point numbers.

Comment: `i` should be a `float`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c (but for some reason I don't think marking it as such, and closing it, would be right, here).

Comment: You should learn the difference between integers and floating point numbers. A hint: Integers don't have fractional parts, so there is no decimal point.

Comment: Don't reuse variables! Declare two separate ones. (For instance, you reuse `i` inside your for loop.)

Comment: *"The above will produce: `34 45 12 3 100 34 6 50`"* - with which compiler/version, and language locale?  I would normally expect it to produce only `34 45 12`, as the `.` in `12.3` should cause the `while (ss >> i)` loop to terminate, and indeed I get only `34 45 12` in testing on VS2013 / MSVC12 on Win7 set to English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code interprets 12.3 as two different numbers because you haven't declared that number as a float. You vector holds all of the strings as integers, and not floats. If you declared your vectors as floats instead of integers, then your problem should be solved

Answer (score 3):

You should use a float and change the code to use float instead of int:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "34,45,12.3,100,34.6,50";
    std::vector<float> vect;

    std::stringstream ss(str);

    float i;

    while (ss >> i)
    {
        vect.push_back(i);

        if (ss.peek() == ',')
        ss.ignore();
    }

    for (i=0; i< vect.size(); i++)
    std::cout << vect.at(i)<<std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should declare  `float i` instead of `int i` and declare the vector as a vector of floats instead of a vector of integers. This is because 12.4 is not an integer, but a float.